# How to run a For loop using a variable with value determined by prompt

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables, prompt

Basically:
a normal for loop would be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
something here }
```

BUT my code/for loop are like this:

```
var numberPeople = parseInt(prompt("How many people are there?"));
for (var numberPeople = 0; numberPeople >=0; numberPeople++) {
people.names.push(prompt("Please enter the person's name", "")); }
```

I need to use the number entered in the first prompt, which fills the variable `numberPeople` to determine how many times the for loop sends a prompt asking for the names.

Comment: Since you are using simple JS code. 
In your browser right-click on the page -> choose inspect -> select console tab.
Paste your code there, it will show the errors more clearly for you

Comment: What do you think happens when you use the same variable to be more than one thing? `var numberPeople = parseInt(...); var numberPeople = 0`

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the for loop condition.
You are re-initializing the `numberPeople` variable to 0 which is why the loop doesn't work. You need to set another variable, for example, `i` to keep track of the iterations in the loop.

```js
var numberPeople = parseInt(prompt("How many people are there?"));
for (var i = 0; i < numberPeople ; i++) {
    people.names.push(prompt("Please enter the person's name", "")); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your for loop, you are initialising another variable called numberPeople, which is being used as opposed to the numberPeople you set with the parseInt.. so why not looping it like this?

```
var numberPeople = parseInt(prompt("How many people are there?"));
for (var i = 0; i < numberPeople; i++) {
people.names.push(prompt("Please enter the person's name", "")); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var numberPeople = parseInt(prompt("How many people are there?"));
var people = {names: []}

for (var i = 0; i < numberPeople; i++) {
    people.names.push(prompt("Please enter the person's name", "")); 
}
```

Just initialize the people variable with the object with the names property.